# What is the proper way to get continuously processed data from a thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, thread-safety, qt5

The following functions and fields are part of the same class in a Visual Studio DLL. Data is continuously being read and processed using the `run` function on a thread. However, `getPoints` is being accessed in a `Qt` app on a `QTimer`. I don't wan't to miss a single processed vector, because it seems it could be skipping leading to jumpy data. What's the safest way to get the points to the updated version?

If possible I'd like an answer that uses the C++ standard library as I've been exploring mutex-es, but it still seems to lead to jumpy data.

```
vector<float> points;
// std::mutex ioMutex;

// function running on a thread
void run(){
    while(running){
        //ioMutex.lock()
        vector<byte> data =  ReadData()
        points = processData(data);
        //ioMutex.unlock()
    }
}

vector<float> getPoints(){
    return points;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a mistake in your code. The while loop will consume all the process activity and will not allow proper functionality of other functions. In Qt, in such continuous loops, usually it is a good habit to use the following because it actually gives other process time to access the event buffer properly. If this dll is written in Qt, please add the following within the while loop

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

Comment: Calling `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` only makes sense if you are calling it from the main/GUI thread.  According to the comments in the questioner's code, `run()` is being called from a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

The safest (and probably easiest) way to deliver your points-data to the main thread is by calling `qApp->postEvent()` with an object of a custom QEvent-subclass that contains your `vector<float>` as a member-variable.

That will cause the `event(QEvent *)` method of (whatever Qt object you specified as the first argument to `postEvent()`) to be called from inside the main/GUI thread, and so you can override that method to read the `vector<float>` out of the QEvent-subclassed object and update the GUI with that data.